# Trigger is trying to insert duplicate key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a trigger that is fired on Insert. This trigger inserts on another table. here is my code:

```
    SELECT @maxTeamId = 0
SELECT @maxTeamId = ISNULL(MAX(teamId), 0) from [dbo].[tblTeamslist]

--- Check if home team has already been inserted into the table.
SELECT @homeTeamId = -1
SELECT 
    @homeTeamId = teamId 
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblTeamslist] t
    JOIN inserted i
    ON t.teamName = i.hometeam
IF (@homeTeamId = -1) 
BEGIN
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblteamslist ON
    SELECT @homeTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
    SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTeamslist] (teamid,teamname) SELECT @homeTeamId, i.hometeam FROM inserted i
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblteamslist off
END

--- Check if away team has already been inserted into the table.
SELECT @awayTeamId = -1
SELECT 
    @awayTeamId = teamId 
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblTeamslist] t
    JOIN inserted i
    ON t.teamName = i.awayteam
IF (@awayTeamId = -1) 
BEGIN
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblteamslist ON
    SELECT @awayTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
    SELECT @maxTeamId = @maxTeamId + 1
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblTeamslist]  (teamid,teamname) SELECT @awayTeamId, i.awayteam FROM inserted i
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblteamslist off
END
```

As you realized I am trying to input a team that if it is not exists on tblTeamsList. Here is the error that i am getting 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblTeamsList'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblTeamsList'. The duplicate key value is (24).'. 
In the code i am trying to increase the id by +1 each time. What is going wrong ?

Comment: Do you realise that `inserted` table can at times hold multiple rows? `@awayTeamId` would be the same for multipe rows in that case.

Comment: First of all, what type o trigger is that (after/instead)? What table your trigger is attached to? Why are you trying to control the ID when the teamid is already an identity column? In your code that is very likely that you are inserting twice with the same teamid.

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios in which this error can happen.
1) if you insert more than one row in a single insert statement, the trigger will fire only once. INSERTED in that case (as mentioned by Chris) will contain more than one row. The inserts into tblTeamList now also will try to insert more than one row - all with the same teamid.

2) If two of these inserts happen at the same time it is possible that they both read the same @maxTeamId. If that happens they both will try to insert a record into tblTeamList with the same teamid.

To prevent both problems use the identity functionality on the table instead of trying to go around it.

Comment: what do you mean  use the identity functionality on the table?, i tried to let the database to insert the Id but it causes an error!